# How to make create two list with one generator in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance

I am trying to create two separate lists from a base list with only one generator but do not know how to do it.

this is the idea, I am wondering if there is a way to create the list's b and c below while only looping through a once.

a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

b = [x[:2] for x in a]

c = [x[2:] for x in a]

What I did before this was just use a for loop through a and constantly append x[:2], x[2:] to b, c with every iteration but after using timeit module I found that using a generator is actually faster, and so I moved on to using two separate generators but now after using timeit with the above python code it seems to be just as slow as before the generators. I suspect it is because I am iterating through the list a twice now.

So basically my question is, what is the most efficient way to create b and c given a two dimensional list, for my application the base list, a, are quite large and so I need it as efficient as possible.

Comment: I think you should definitively use Numpy for that (using Numpy 2D slicing).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, list a and b contain the same data, so use generator to create first list and then copy list a to list b.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I would suggest to keep using list comprehension and bench mark before making any optimizations (if you really think you need them).

I tried four ways:

Using loops:

```
def use_loop(a):
    b = []
    c = []
    for item in a:
        b.append(item[:2])
        c.append(item[2:])
    return (b,c)
```

Using list comprehension twice:

```
def use_comprehension(a):
    b = [x[:2] for x in a]
    c = [x[2:] for x in a]
    return (b,c)
```

Using list comprehension with zip

```
def use_comprehension_with_zip(a):
    data = [[], []]
    b, c = zip(*[(x[:2], x[2:]) for x in a])
    return (list(b),list(c))
```

Usings threads is overkill and it will definitely increase your time.

```
def get_shorter_list(a, index, ans):
    if index == 0:
        for item in a:
            ans.append(item[:2])
    else:
        for item in a:
            ans.append(item[2:])

def use_threads(a):
    b = []
    c = []
    data = {0:b, 1:c}
    threads = []
    for x in range(2):
        thread = threading.Thread(target = get_shorter_list, args=(a, x, data.get(x)))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    return (b,c)
```

Then I used timeit for the three methods

```
function_list = [
                use_loop,
                use_comprehension,
                use_comprehension_with_zip,
                use_threads
                ]

assert use_loop(a) == use_comprehension(a) == use_comprehension_with_zip(a) == use_threads(a)

for function in function_list:
    print(f'Time taken by {function.__name__}: {timeit.timeit("function(a)", globals = globals(), number = 10000)}')
```

That did not show a huge degradation by using list comprehension which I always prefer for clarity, brevity and speed.

```
Time taken by use_loop: 0.01102178400469711
Time taken by use_comprehension: 0.011585937994823325
Time taken by use_comprehension_with_zip: 0.0187399349961197
Time taken by use_threads: 2.036599840997951
```